# Swipe to popBackStack in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Swipe to close the picture browser similar to Twitter.

I implemented something simply and it is much worse.

[Video demonstration effect](https://youtube.com/shorts/_Pxa0yhUrno?feature=share)

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ScrollableSample() {


    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }


    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        Box(
            Modifier
                .offset { IntOffset(0, offsetY.roundToInt()) }
                .background(Color.Blue)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(400.dp)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures(
                        onDragStart = {

                        },
                        onDragEnd = {
                            println(offsetY)
                        }) { change, dragAmount ->
                        change.consume()
                        offsetY += dragAmount.y
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```